# Google APP Engine datastorage design

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, type-kinds

I'm currently building a website on AppEngine using Python, and I've to store some informations on datastore.

All my informations are splits in three different categories as following:

1°/- Article (Main page news entries).
2°/- Products (Products page description entries).
3°/- Navigation (Contain all the header menu entries).

For now, I'm storing them like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class article(db.Model):

    title = db.StringProperty()
    body = db.TextProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    aside = db.StringProperty()
    comment = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class navigation(db.Model):

    title = db.StringProperty()
    comment = db.StringProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()

class products(db.Model):

    title = db.StringProperty()
    body = db.TextProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    aside = db.StringProperty()
    comment = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I know this is not optimized and as you can see, my products class is the same one as the article. I think I can derive it from the article one, or extend it from, but I'm not sure.

So my questions are:

Do I need to use namespaces? (I want to clearly separate the articles from the products).

What's the usual design for that kind of datastorage?

My article body property would never have to be longer than 50 words, how could I limit the stringProperty range? Do I have to set it during my call to this property or is there any options to put on the default method of the DB class?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand: An author can write / comment an article which is about one (only one?) product having a description and other properties, so I guess we should have something like this

```
class products(db.Model):
    name_product = db.StringProperty()   # For Example
    description_product = db.StringProperty()   # For Example


class article(db.Model):
    my_product = db.ReferenceProperty(products, required=True)

    # Properties of the article
    title = db.StringProperty()   
    body = db.TextProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    aside = db.StringProperty()
    comment = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

In the case where one article would concern several products, then you may create another db model for mapping the articles and products. Since several products can be mentionned in several article, we would have:

```
class products(db.Model):
    name_product = db.StringProperty()   # For Example
    description_product = db.StringProperty()   # For Example


class article(db.Model):
    # Properties of the article
    title = db.StringProperty()   
    body = db.TextProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    aside = db.StringProperty()
    comment = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class map_Article_Products(db.Model):
    my_article = db.ReferenceProperty(article, required=True)
    my_product = db.ReferenceProperty(products, required=True)
```

***Note that the db model "article" changes in this case***

Comment: Not exactly.

In fact, Articles are just the news contain into a slideshow zone, so the body is only a short text.

And Products are the product description, but the pattern of a product is the same that for articles. Except that the body is more longer than 500 chars so it's a TextProperty.

Answer (score 0):

To the 50 words limit: Create your own variant of StringProperty, that validates against this limit before storing. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/extending_models for a detailed example.